# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'range

Tags: php, mysql, json

Lines of sql code:

```
$uid=$_POST["uid"];
$mobile=$_POST["mobile"];
$service=$_POST["service"];
$exper=$_POST["exper"];
$range=$_POST["range"];
$af=$_POST["a_from"];
$at=$_POST["a_to"];
$min_charge=$_POST["min_charge"];

$statement=mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO service (uid,mobile,service,exper,range,a_from,a_to,min_charge) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"iisiiiii",$uid,$mobile,$service,$exper,$range,$af,$at,$min_charge);

mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response=array();
$response["success"]=true;

echo mysqli_error($con);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Everything is ok, and I don't get any syntax error when I write the code (I am using a code editor software. However, when I use it online, I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'range,a_from,a_to,min_charge) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'

Comment: 1st post of 5 about sql that the OP actually is NOT using a decrecated sql libs. Your on the right track Sachin

Answer (score 2):

This is not obvious. `range` is a reserved word. It makes a lousy column name, but if you use it, you need to escape it:

```
INSERT INTO service (uid, mobile, service, exper, `range`, a_from, a_to, min_charge)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) is the list of reserved words.

For those who are curious, `RANGE` is a type of partitioning. You can read about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html). I am not sure why MySQL needs to reserve this, given that many keywords are not actually reserved.

I should add: Reserved word such as `FROM`, `TO`, or `GROUP` are obvious, but to me `RANGE` is rather unexpected as a reserved word, given that many syntactic elements are not reserved, such as `OFFSET`, `PARTITIONS`, `HASH` (also used for partitioning), `HOUR`, `BEGIN`.

Comment: *"But RANGE is rather unexpected as a reserved word."* - I don't quite understand what you meant by that. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html `RANGE (R)`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- . . . Totally subjective.  To me it is unexpected when `RANGE` and `PARTITION` are reserved but `HASH` and `PARTITIONS` are not.  They are all keywords for the same clause.

Comment: If you do this, I would escape all columns, for consistency.

Comment: oh great , now my code working. thanks...Gordon Linoff